# Easiest way to preview https over localhost?

Tags: https, localhost

I'm creating a site that will be served over `https` when deployed. That means urls in the links of the site et cetera are `https://...` But now it's in an emerging state and I preview it on `localhost`.

Basically I just want to be able to keep the urls beginning with `https` and still be able to preview the site on localhost. The whole site will be `https` when deployed, so during development I don't need to know which is which, I just need to be able to preview the url even though they say `https`.

I could create a [self-signed certificate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-signed_certificate) for the page on `localhost` ... **but I wonder if there is an easier, maybe ugly, way?**

I run Apache on Linux.

---

A workaround would of course be to replace `https` with `http` during development and then switch back when the site is deployed. In my case this would only need to be done in one place (where I set the constant defining the hostname).

Comment: If you're testing with a web browser, just add a security exception for the site and store it in the browser. You usually do this when the browser says it's blocking the site due to security issues.

Comment: @JMC Could you elaborate a bit on that? I don't think the server (I use Apache for localhost) will serve `https:` urls if I don't have a certificate set up? I just get a "Connection failed" and I thought that was the standard behaviour?

Comment: What is your goal here? Do you want to test the general functionality of the website on localhost, without getting errors because of the https links (in which case you could probably work with htaccess rewrite rules or some browser plugins to automatically go to http instead of https), or do you want to also test the correctness of the links (eg it's https if it needs to be) and everything else that may have to do with https (this would be more difficult without actually setting up https)? And what server setup do you have (apache, php, ...)?

Comment: @tim Good questions. I added some to mine. I don't need to test the correctness of the links (this time), so a rewrite rule could work. But it would be nice if there was a way to see the links as they should be, with `https`, that would be more useful for other scenarios.

Comment: @tim "without getting errors" - you wouldn't be able to use "htaccess rewrite rules" to avoid an "error", since any HTTPS/SSL security error would occur _before_ .htaccess gets a chance to do anything.

Comment: @w3dk You are right, I didn't really think that through, there would of course still be errors. That would probably leave some kind of browser plugin, like a reverse https everywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the solution of not using absolute links within the site to itself.  Instead of:

```
<a href="https://example.com/page.html">
```

Use protocol relative links:

```
<a href="//example.com/page.html">
```

Or root relative links:

```
<a href="/page.html">
```

Then your site works on your development server even if you view it over `http` rather than `https`.

Comment: Nice idea. Are there any potential drawbacks with this approach?

Comment: I do this with all my sites.   It saves bytes as well.     The only drawback is that if somebody (or a crawler) finds your site on an alternate domain, they won't make their way back to the canonical site name by clicking links.

Comment: Classic, simple, and perfect.